# Can I model in JAXB an element that sometimes contains other elements and sometimes direct data

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

A webservice sometimes  provide an element in the form

```
<artist>
<name>name</name>
</artist>
```

and sometimes like

```
<artist>name</artist>
```

I'm not in control of the webservice so cannot change this

I read the results into a JAXB model. Is it possible to model this inconsistency in JAXB, my model currently only represent the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to intercept the webservice message before it's passed to JAXB, you could transform it (for example using XSLT) into the form which works with your current JAXB model. If you can't do that, it's a bit ugly to process but you could try modelling those two message forms as mixed content, allowing you to represent the content as a string or an element containing that string.

For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "artist")
public class Artist {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "name", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
}

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName NAME_QNAME = new QName("", "name");
    public ObjectFactory() {}

    public Artist createArtist() {
        return new Artist();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "name", scope = Artist.class)
    public JAXBElement<String> createArtistName(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(NAME_QNAME, String.class, Artist.class, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Also note that there's a `JAXBSource` and `JAXBResult` class that can be used to directly transform from/to XML/beans using XSLT.You could put it in from of the unmarshaller to transform the XML and get the bean the way you want it.

Comment: I transformed it beforehand and did a String replace which works. But is it possible to edit the Schema that JAXB classes are derived from to generate the right code or not ?

Comment: If you want to try the mixed content suggestion, add mixed="true" to the complex type for "artist" in your schema. e.g. <xs:complexType mixed="true">. Then regenerate your classes.